# Extract files from folders according to folder name list from csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a master file with more than 1000 subfolders, e.g. Folder 1, Folder 2, Folder 3... Folder 1000. Inside those subfolders there are images in each.

I have a csv which shows the subfolders I would like the images to be extracted from, e.g. Folder 3, Folder 7 and Folder 10.

So far I have managed to write of script of reading the desired subfolder names from the csv, but how can I make it to extract those images under the particular subfolders?

Current code shown below:

```
import csv
with open("XXX.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    treelist = []
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',') 
    for lines in csv_reader:
        x = lines['TREE_MARK']
        treelist.append(x)
 
    print(treelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of how you could achieve this. I am using pathlib to get file paths, pandas to read the subfolders, glob to go through the sub-folders and get every image (.png in my case) and skimage for reading the images

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from skimage import io

working_dir = Path('.')
# get list of desired folders
df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv', names=['folder_names'])
# traverse through folders
for file in df['folder_names']:
  # get complete file path
  file_path = Path(working_dir.absolute(), file)
  # look for png images in each sub folder
  for file in file_path.glob('*.png'):
    # read image
    img = io.imread(file)
    # process here...
```

Edit: based on your output in the comments:
Assuming you have a list as

`folder_list = ['Folder 3', 'Folder 7', 'Folder 10']`

you can traverse through the list and read individual images as in my answer above

```
# traverse through folders
for folder in folder_list:
  # get complete folder path
  file_path = Path(working_dir.absolute(), folder)
  # look for png images in each sub folder
  for file in file_path.glob('*.png'):
    # read image
    img = io.imread(file)
    # process here...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but what if I have produced an outcome from the script in the following format e.g. ['Folder 3', 'Folder '7', Folder '10'] and I only want to import images from these three subfolders?